# translate mysql query into rails scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I looking to turn this mysql query into a rails scope in a model called stats. Here is an example of the expected results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  scope :by_content, -> {
    select("date, title").
    group(:title).
    order("title")
  }


SELECT s.date as date, s.title as title,
  count(F.id) as impressions,
  count(D.event) as completed
FROM stats s
  Left Join stats as F on s.id = F.id and F.event ='play' and F.videopos = '0'
  Left Join stats as D on s.id = D.id and D.event = 'completed'
WHERE s.user_id = '2'
AND (s.date_time between '2014-03-08 00:00:00' and '2014-03-18 23:59:59')
AND s.title is not null
GROUP BY s.title
```

Comment: You actually want to know how to translate raw sql with ActiveRecord querying. The scoping part is straightforward. This railsguide should help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html. One additional note, I wouldn't put all this code in a single scope. You don't want a single scope to get massive. Better chain multiple scopes or write a class method for it.

Comment: Thanks @rails4guides.com I solved it with this.

scope :impressions, -> {
    joins("Left Join stats as F on stats.id = F.id and F.event ='play' and F.videopos = '0'").
    select("stats.id, stats.title as title, count(F.id) as impressions, (count(D.event) / count(F.id)) as completed")
  }
  scope :completed,   -> {
    joins("Left Join stats as D on stats.id = D.id and D.event = 'completed'")
  }
  scope :by_title,    -> {
    group(:title).
    where("stats.title is not null").
    order("count(stats.id) DESC")
  }

Comment: @jnbankston please update your post by answering your question with your solution. The code will be much more readable in the Q&A rather than comments.